# Change Style based on string length

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles

so i have an array which gets multiple strings based on displayed charts. Now i am looking for the longest string within this array. Right now this works without problems.

The code for this looks like:

```
var textLengthArray = [];
            domContainer.find(" g > .element1 > .element2> text").each(function () {
                textLengthArray.push($(this).text());
            });


            var longestString = textLengthArray.sort(function (a, b) {
                return b.length - a.length;
            })[0];
```

Now i want to change the font size of those "text" elements based on the longest string. So if the longest string within the array is longer than 10 characters, the font-size should be changed to "x px/pt".

My first thoughts are all about something like:

```
 if (longestString >= 10){
 domContainer.find(" g > .brm-y-direction > .tick > text")
.style('font-size', '4pt')                            
            };
```

i also have tried something like:

```
if (longestString >= 2){
   $("g.brm-y-direction.tick").find("text").css("font-size", "4pt") ;  };
```

But those solutions didnot work at all. So can anyone tell me how to solve this via javascript?

The generated HTML text looks like:

```
<g class="tick" transform="translate(0,74)" style="opacity: 1;">
     <line x2="-6" y2="0"></line>
            <text dy=".32em" x="-12" y="37" style="text-anchor: end;">sampletext</text></g>
```

Comment: Could you include a sample of the HTML of the element you're trying to set the font-size of?

Comment: You might wanna add a jQuery tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see `brm-y-direction` in your HTML snippet, so you could try

```
$("g.tick text").css("font-size", "4pt");
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much!